# How to generate pdf of html page in java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I have to generate pdf of HTML page. I have written a method for this but it generates an error. Please guide me where I'm wrong. Thank You!

```
public void htmlToPdf(
    String htmlPath, 
    File pdfFile
) throws IOException, DocumentException { 
    Document document = new Document(); 
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(
        document, 
        new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)
    ); 
    document.open(); 
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(
        writer, 
        document, 
        new FileInputStream(htmlPath), 
        Charset.forName("UTF-8")
    ); 
    document.close(); 
}
```

Error :

```
Cannot resolve method 'parseXHtml(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter,  com.lowagie.text.Document, java.io.FileInputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'
```

Comment: You appear to be using the `XmlWorker` from some 5.x version and itext from a pre-5 version. That cannot work. Please use matching versions.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to generate PDFs from HTML with Java? **(check EDIT 2020 at the bottom)**

Here is the procedure I am using with [flying-saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer).

1. Format your HTML with CSS 2.1
2. Write the process to generate a PDF
3. Create the PDF generator interface
4. Use a custom object to wrap images with attributes for further formatting
5. Implements your interface with your PDF parameters and images

#### 1. Format your HTML with CSS 2.1

Example can be a JSP with ELs, any other template (you will be able to get the
generated HTML with parameters with an internal POST request), or just static
HTML.

You cannot use proportionnal values like `em`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw` or complex
CSS like animations.

You can use `<style> </style>` tag or inline `style=` attribute

Here is an example of a JSP in my webapp.

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page    session="false" 
            language="java" 
            contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
            pageEncoding="UTF-8" 
            isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <META CHARSET="UTF-8" />
        <title>My PDF</title>
        <style>
            /* you can add reset css too */
            /* stylesheet */
            body { font-family: sans-serif; }
            .someCSSClass {}
            .anotherCSSClass {}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="someCSSClass">
            <p class="anotherCSSClass" style="line-height:16px;">
                ${ param.aParameter }
            </p>
```

#### 2. Write the process to generate a PDF with an interface

Why using an interface? Because in the case you need to generate additional
PDFs from different models you will not have to write the same logic to
generate each PDFs.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import main.java.bean.ImagePDF;
import main.java.interface.PDFInterface;
import main.java.bean.Constants;
/**
 * PDFGenerator
 * Class to generate PDF (can implement Servlet).
 */
public class PDFGenerator {
    private static final String TMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    /* 
     * May not be a GET, can be simple method call for local application or
     * whatever you need
     */ 
    @Override
    protected void goGet(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException {
        PDFInterface pdfImplementation = null;
        /*
         * instance your PDF Model implementation according to this 
         * parameter (for example)
         */
        int pdfModel = Integer.parseInt(
            request.getParameter("requestedPDFModel")
        );
        switch (pdfModel) {
            case Constants.PDF_MODEL_1:
                pdfImplementation = new PDFImplementationOne();
                /* 
                 * You could get the image reference from GET request too, 
                 * or from database or from constants
                 */
                pdfImplementation.addImage(
                    "image1.png", 
                    120, 
                    50, 
                    "image_name1", 
                    request
                );
                break;
            case Constants.PDF_MODEL_2:
                pdfImplementation = new PDFImplementationTwo();
                pdfImplementation.addImage(
                    "image2.png", 
                    350, 
                    70, 
                    "image_name2", 
                    request
                );
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Cannot find an implementation for the requested PDF.");
                return null;
        }
        String html = null;
        /*
            Get the HTML from an URL : if your implementation returns null
            then you can for example decide to get the HTML from a file in your implementation
        */
        if (pdfImplementation.getUrl(request) != null) {
            // Send POST request to generate the HTML from a template (JSP, JSF, Thymeleaf, ...)
            URLConnection connection = new URL(
                pdfImplementation.getUrl(request)
                +pdfImplementation.getEncodedQueryString()
            ).openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // POST : remove this to do a GET
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                "Content-Type", 
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
            );
            try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                output.write(
                    pdfImplementation
                        .getEncodedQueryString()
                        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                );
            }
            // Open an input stream on the response
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())
            );
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // A line in our generated HTML
            String inputLine;
            // Read all HTML lines and concatenate
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                sb.append(inputLine); 
            }
            html = sb.toString();
            in.close();
        }
        // Get the HTML from a File
        else {
            html = String.join(
                "", 
                Files.readAllLines(pdfImplementation.getHTMLFile().toPath())
            );
        }
        // Create a temp file to make the PDF
        File tempPDFFile = new File(
            TMP_DIR + pdfImplementation.getGeneratedPDFFileName()
        );
        if (!tempPDFFile.exists()) { tempPDFFile.createNewFile(); }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempPDFFile);
        // Output the HTML to the temp PDF file
        new ITextRenderer() {{
            setDocumentFromString(html);
            layout();
            createPDF(fos);
        }};
        fos.close();
        // Create your final PDF file
        File pdf = new File(pdfImplementation.getPDFFilename());
        // Add images if needed
        addImageToPDF(pdfImplementation, tempPDFFile, pdf);
        // Write in response if you need servlet implementation
        writePDFContentToResponse(pdf, response);
    }
    /**
     * writePDFContentToResponse
     * @param pdf : the final PDF file
     * @param response :  a HTTPServletResponse to write PDF file bytes
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void writePDFContentToResponse(
        File pdf, 
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        String mimeType = getServlet().getServletContext()
            .getMimeType(pdf.getAbsolutePath());
        response.setContentType(
            mimeType != null ? mimeType : "application/octet-stream"
        );
        response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());
        response.setHeader(
            "Content-Disposition", 
            "attachment; filename="+pdf.getName()+".pdf"
        );
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while((read = fis.read(bufferData)) != -1) { 
            os.write(bufferData, 0, read); 
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        fis.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
        Files.delete(pdf.toPath());
    }
    /**
     * addImageToPDF
     * 
     * @param pdfImplementation : the pdfImplementation to get the array of
     * custom image objects ImagePDF.
     * @param tempPDFFile : the temp PDF file with already HTML content 
     * converted.
     * @param pdf : the final PDF file which will have images stamped.
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void addImageToPDF(
        PDFInterface pdfImplementation, 
        File tempPDFFile, 
        File pdf
    ) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(tempPDFFile));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
            reader, 
            new FileOutputStream(pdf)
        );
        for (ImagePDF img: pdfImplementation.getImages()) {
            Image image = img.getImage();
            image.scalePercent(img.getScale());
            PdfImage stream = new PdfImage(image, "", null);
            stream.put(
                new PdfName("ITXT_SpecialId"), 
                new PdfName("123456789")
            );
            PdfIndirectObject ref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream);
            image.setDirectReference(ref.getIndirectReference());
            image.setAbsolutePosition(
                img.getWidthPosition(), 
                img.getHeightPosition()
            );
            PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
            over.addImage(image);
        }
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

#### 3. Create the PDF generator interface

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
/**
* PDFInterface
* Interface to define the behavior a PDF model has to implement.
*/
public interface PDFInterface {
    /**
     * getUrl
     * @param request the HTTPServletRequest to fetch parameters for the PDF
     * @return the URL target to make a HTTP POST request to get the generated
     * HTML (for example if you are making a HTTP POST on a JSP to generate
     * HTML dynamically.
     */
    String getUrl(HttpServletRequest request);
    /**
     * getHTMLFile
     * @return return the HTML file from the local storage to be read to get 
     * the HTML.
     */
    File getHTMLFile();
    /**
     * setParametres
     * @param object : an object or a list of objects to be encoded to the
     * query String to generate the PDF.
     */
    void setParametres(Candidat candidat);

    String getEncodedQueryString();
    /**
     * getImages
     * @return a custom ImagePDF object with needed attributes to add an image
     * after the PDF has been generated has the HTML cannot be read to get
     * image during the generation of the PDF.
     */
    List<ImagePDF> getImages();
    /**
     * addImage
     * @param url : the URL to get the image
     * @param x : the X position
     * @param y : the Y position
     * @param name : the name of the image
     * @param request : the HTTPServletRequest to generate the relative link 
     * to fetch the image.
     * @param scale : the scale of the image
     * @throws BadElementException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void addImage(
        String url,
        float x,
        float y,
        String name,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        float scale
    ) throws BadElementException, IOException;
    /**
     * getPDFFilename
     * @return : the name of the PDF file to be generated
     */
    String getPDFFilename();
}
```

#### 4. The ImagePDF object (in case you need to add image to your PDF)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
/**
 * ImagePDF
 * Class for a custom ImagePDF object to fit needs to stamp an image on a
 * generated PDF (URI to get the image, scale, positions x y ...).
 */
public class ImagePDF implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image image;
    private float widthPosition;
    private float heightPosition;
    private String name;
    private Float scale;
    /**
     * ImagePDF
     * @param urlImage : the URL to fetch the image
     * @param heightPosition : the y position on the PDF canvas
     * @param widthPosition : the x position on the PDF canvas
     * @param name : the name of the image
     * @param scale : the scale of the image on the PDF canvas
     * @throws BadElementException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public ImagePDF(
        String urlImage,
        float widthPosition,
        float heightPosition,
        String name,
        Float scale
    ) throws BadElementException, IOException {
        this.image = Image.getInstance(urlImage);
        this.heightPosition = heightPosition;
        this.widthPosition = widthPosition;
        this.name = name;
        this.scale = scale;
    }
    // Getters and setters ...
```

#### 5. Implements your interface for your PDF parameters

(used in example above)

```java
/**
 * PDFImplementationOne
 * The PDFImplementation to generate a specific PDF.
 */
public class PDFImplementationOne implements PDFInterface {
    private static final String PARAM_1 = "param1";
    private static final String PARAM_2 = "param2";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private List<ImagePDF> images;
    /**
     * PDFImplementationOne
     * You can pass service to add information retreival from DB or objects to 
     * pass to parameters in the constructor if needed.
     */
    public PDFImplementationOne (CustomObject aParameter) {
        this.parameters = new HashMap<>();
        this.images = new ArrayList<>();
        // in case you need parameters, passed in constructor
        setParametres(aParameter); 
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see main.java.interface.PDFInterface#getUrl()
     */
    @Override
    public String getUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        /* 
         * This is an example in case your generate your HTML from JSP with 
         * parameters, if it is from static file then return null
         */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("http://");
        sb.append(request.getServerName());
        sb.append((request.getServerName().startsWith("127.0.0")?":8080":""));
        sb.append("/MyApp/urlToJSP");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see main.java.interface.PDFInterface#addImage(
     *  java.lang.String, 
     *  float, 
     *  float, 
     *  java.lang.String, 
     *  javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
     *  float scale
     * )
     */
    @Override
    public void addImage(
        String fileName,
        float x,
        float y,
        String name,
        HttpServletRequest request
    ) {
        /* 
         * Here I get the image from a ressource server but you can read the 
         * image from local storage as well
         */
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://");
        url.append(request.getServerName());
        url.append(request.getServerName().startsWith("127.0.0")?":8080":"");
        url.append("/MyApp/img/");
        url.append(fileName);
        try {
            ImagePDF image = new ImagePDF(url.toString(), x, y, name, scale);
            images.add(image);
        }
        catch (BadElementException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(Cannot set image for PDF "+url.toString());
        }
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see main.java.interface.PDFInterface#getImages()
     */
    @Override
    public List<ImagePDF> getImages() {
        return this.images;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see main.java.interface.PDFInterface#setParameters(
     *  CustomObject customObject
     * )
     */
    @Override
    public void setParametres(CustomObject customObject) {
        parametres.put(PARAM_1, customObject.getAttribute().toString());
        // may have other parameters ...
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see model.bean.ResultatsEcritsPDF#getEncodedQueryString()
     */
    @Override
    public String getEncodedQueryString() {
        /* 
         * Create the queryString to do further HTTP POST or GET to fetch the 
         * generated HTML with parameters
         */
        StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("?");
        parameters.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            queryStringBuilder.append(e.getKey());
            queryStringBuilder.append("=");
            try {
                queryStringBuilder.append(
                    URLEncoder.encode(
                        e.getValue() == null 
                            ? "" 
                            : e.getValue(), 
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
                    )
                );
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                queryStringBuilder.append("");
            }
            queryStringBuilder.append("&");
        });
        // Remove the last &
        return queryStringBuilder.toString().substring(
            0, 
            queryStringBuilder.toString().length()-1
        );
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see model.bean.PDFInterface#getHTMLFile()
     */
    @Override
    public File getHTMLFile() {
        return new File("/path/to/myHTMLFile.html");
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see model.bean.PDFInterface#getPDFFilename()
     */
    @Override
    public String getPDFFilename() {
        return "myPDF.pdf";
    }
}
```

Tell me if it needs some clarification.

---

### EDIT 2020

Things are much simpler now with the improvement of libraries and calling HTTP server itself to generate the dynamic HTML content is not enough simpler and requires additional network configuration in some case.

Here is the new process :

- Make a HTML template with CSS2.1 (with `<style>` tag or `inline style="`) and include template expressions (EL-style or whatever)
- Fetch HTML template as String
- Replace template expressions "${ }" in HTML
- Replace images in HTML like `<img src="image.png" />` by encoded base64 images
- Make the PDF file
- Write it to response or whatever

#### Here is the project structure I am using (for example) :

```
main
 |--java
     |--bean
         |--PdfConverter.java
 |--resources
     |--pdf
         |--template.html
         |--img
              |--image.png
```

#### Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.20</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.20</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.20</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

#### HTML template (with images) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:14px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0; 
            }
            h1 { 
                text-align:center;
                font-size:21px;
                text-transform:capitalize;
            }
        </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>some title</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph : ${ foo }</p>
        <!-- you can style images with CSS! -->
        <img src="image.png" style="width:50px;height:50px" />
    </body>
</html>
```

#### PdfConverter :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
/**
 * PdfConverter
 * Extends this to implement additional to make the map to replace template
 * expressions.
 * @author user
 * @since 28 juil. 2020
 */
public class PdfConverter {
    /**
     * Temp directory.
     */
    private static final String TMP_DIR =
        System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/";
    /**
     * Directory to HTML templates (dedicated to PDF generation).
     */
    private static final String PDF_DIR =
        "pdf/";
    /**
     * Directory to the image folders (dedicated to PDF generation).
     */
    private static final String PDF_IMG_DIR =
        "pdf/img/";
    /**
     * Prefixes for templates expressions.
     */
    private static final String PREFIX_TEMPLATE = "${ ";
    /**
     * Suffixes for template expressions.
     */
    private static final String SUFFIX_TEMPLATE = " }";
    /**
     * Generated PDF file.
     */
    private File generatedPDF;
    /**
     * PDF file name.
     */
    private String pdfName;
    /**
     * PdfConverter
     * @param m map key, value to replace, to replace expressions in HTML
     * template.
     * @param s ServletContext to get resources from context path.
     * @param fileName desired name of the generated PDF.
     * @param template name of the HTML template to make the PDF.
     * @throws IOExceptio
     */
    public PdfConverter(
        Map<String, String> m,
        ServletContext s,
        String fileName,
        String template
    ) throws IOException {
        // Set PDF filename
        setPdfName(fileName);

        // Fetch HTML template
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        String html = new Scanner(
            s.getResourceAsStream(PDF_DIR+ template),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
        ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        /*
         * Replace template expressions "${ }" in HTML
         */
        StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(
            m,
            PREFIX_TEMPLATE,
            SUFFIX_TEMPLATE
        );
        String resolvedString = sub.replace(html);

        /*
         * Replace images like <img src="image.png" /> by
         * <img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + base64Image
         */
        String[] imgs = StringUtils.substringsBetween(
            resolvedString,
            "<img src=\"", "\""
        );
        for (String s1 : imgs) {
            String mime = Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(PDF_IMG_DIR + s1));
            resolvedString = resolvedString.replace(
                s1,
                "data:" + mime + ";base64,"
                 + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                    IOUtils.toByteArray(
                        s.getResourceAsStream(PDF_IMG_DIR + s1)
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        // Make the PDF file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(TMP_DIR+getPdfName());
        ITextRenderer it = new ITextRenderer();
        it.setDocumentFromString(resolvedString);
        it.layout();
        it.createPDF(fos);
        fos.close();

        // Set the PDF generated file to this PdfConverter instance
        setGeneratedPDF(new File(TMP_DIR+getPdfName()));
    }
    /**
     * getGeneratedPDF
     *
     * @return the generatedPDF
     */
    public File getGeneratedPDF() {
        return generatedPDF;
    }
    /**
     * setGeneratedPDF
     *
     * @param generatedPDF the generatedPDF to set
     */
    public void setGeneratedPDF(File generatedPDF) {
        this.generatedPDF = generatedPDF;
    }
    /**
     * getPdfName
     *
     * @return the pdfName
     */
    public String getPdfName() {
        return pdfName;
    }
    /**
     * setPdfName
     *
     * @param pdfName the pdfName to set
     */
    public void setPdfName(String pdfName) {
        this.pdfName = pdfName;
    }
    /**
     * writePdfToResponse
     * Write the PDF file into the response and delete it from temp directory
     * afterwards.
     * @param response
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void writePdfToResponse(
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException {
        try (
            FileInputStream fis =
                new FileInputStream(getGeneratedPDF())
        ) {
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
            response.setHeader(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "inline; filename=" + getPdfName()
            );
            response.addHeader(
                "Content-Length",
                Long.toString(getGeneratedPDF().length())
            );
            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream =
                response.getOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = fis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
            response.getWriter().print("Cannot render PDF file.");
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
        finally {
            // Delete generated PDF after writing it to the response
            getGeneratedPDF().delete();
        }
    }
}
```

#### And how to use it in servlet (Spring MVC example) :

```
/**
 * downloadPDF
 *
 * @param response
 * @param foo
 * @throws IOException
 */
@PostMapping("/downloadPDF")
public void downloadPDF(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    String foo
) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("foo", "my_foo_value");
    PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter(
        m, 
        request.getServletContext(), 
        "my_pdf", 
        "template"
    );
    pdfConverter.writePdfToResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I also using above same you and generate PDF successfully,
I have a question, How can generate PDF but keeping format (example: css..,)

Actual after generate PDF: http://prntscr.com/o6gysx
Expected results : http://prntscr.com/o6gz4f

Comment: Using this method is compatible with CSS 2.1 so you can do the layout in HTML for your PDF with CSS. Though, you will have to use inline CSS style or `<style> </style>` declarator in your file instead of using stylesheets. You will have also to not use `em`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw`, ... values but `px`, `%` etc. ...

Comment: I see you need to add a picture in your PDF. Adding a picture in PDF cannot be done from HTML. You have to modify the PDF after generation and stamp it with the picture. I'll edit the answer to show how-to.

Comment: Thanks Paul. i don't know how can working at with this.
Currently, i using cucumber reporting .

Comment: Thanks Paul. I don't understand, **getImage()**

PDFStrategy pdfGenerationImpl, 
Image image = img.getImage();

Comment: In fact the process of generating and adding images to PDF is the same for all PDF models so I use an interface for this process and implement it differently for each model (for example to get images from diffents paths).

Comment: I see there is a [tool](https://github.com/brynary/features2cards) for Cucumber to generate PDFs. Have you tried it? If it doesn't fit your needs, tell me how are you getting your HTML, from static file or by doing a `HTTP` request?

Comment: Thanks paul,  I have not try yet tool you share. I will tried it. and feedback for you soon.